# Problem with xsl: remove only the branch that does not contain a particular node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I would like to remove only the areas that do not have the user node

My starting xml file XML:

```
<root>
    <area_1>
        <role_1>
            <user>
                <name>william</name>
            </user>
        </role_1>
        <role_2>
            <user>
                <name>william</name>
            </user>
        </role_2>
    </area_1>
    <area_2>
        <role_1 />
        <role_2>
            <user>
                <name>william</name>
            </user>
        </role_2>
    </area_2>
    <area_3>
        <role_1 />
    </area_3>
</root>
```

This is XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text() or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()])]" />
    <xsl:template match="@*[not(string())]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I lose the rules of the areas where the user node is present.

OUTPUT XML :

```
<root>
   <area_1>
      <role_1>
         <user>
            <name>william</name>
         </user>
      </role_1>
      <role_2>
         <user>
            <name>william</name>
         </user>
      </role_2>
   </area_1>
   <area_2>
      <role_2>
         <user>
            <name>william</name>
         </user>
      </role_2>
   </area_2>
</root>
```

My problem:

I would like to keep the roles of the various branches and remove only the areas that do not have the node user.

I would like to get this result:

```
<root>
    <area_1>
        <role_1>
            <user>
                <name>william</name>
            </user>
        </role_1>
        <role_2>
            <user>
                <name>william</name>
            </user>
        </role_2>
    </area_1>
    <area_2>
        <role_1 /> <!--keep these tags-->
        <role_2>
            <user>
                <name>william</name>
            </user>
        </role_2>
    </area_2>
</root>
```

how could i modify my xsl?
Thanks

Comment: You need to define what exactly is an "area".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> remove only the areas that do not have the node user.

I believe that would translate to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="area[not(descendant::user)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But since you don't have any elements that are actually named `area`, you will need to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'area')][not(descendant::user)]"/>
```

or perhaps:

```
<xsl:template match="/root/*[not(descendant::user)]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **michael.hor257k**!

I used:

```
<xsl:template match="/root/*[not(descendant::user)]"/>
```